# Symfony serializer - set circular reference global

Tags: rest, symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, circular-reference

Is there any way to set the circular reference limit in the serializer component of Symfony (not JMSSerializer) with any config or something like that?

I have a REST Application with FOSRestBundle and some Entities that contain other entities which should be serialized too. But I'm running into circular reference errors.

I know how to set it like this:

```
$encoder    = new JsonEncoder();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
     return $object->getName();
});
```

But this has to be done in more than one controller (overhead for me).
I want to set it globally in the config (.yml) e.g. like this:

```
framework: 
    serializer:
        enabled: true
        circular_limit: 5
```

Found no serializer API reference for this so I wonder is it possible or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I've found is to create your own object normalizer to add the circular reference handler.

A minimal working one can be:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\PropertyTypeExtractorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface;

class AppObjectNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    public function __construct(ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null, NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null, PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null, PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($classMetadataFactory, $nameConverter, $propertyAccessor, $propertyTypeExtractor);

        $this->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
            return $object->getName();
        });
    }
}
```

Then declare as a service with a slithly higher priority than the default one (which is -1000):

```
<service
    id="app.serializer.normalizer.object"
    class="AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\AppObjectNormalizer"
    public="false"
    parent="serializer.normalizer.object">

    <tag name="serializer.normalizer" priority="-500" />
</service>
```

This normalizer will be used by default everywhere in your project.

Comment: The method `\Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer::setCircularReferenceHandler` is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. You should use the `circular_reference_handler` key of the context:

`$this->defaultContext['circular_reference_handler'] = function ($object) { return $object->getName(); };`

Comment: @Konpaka, exactly what should be possible in a config file.

Answer (score 10):

For a week have I been reading Symfony source and trying some tricks to get it work (on my project and without installing a third party bundle: not for that functionality) and I finally got one. I used **CompilerPass** (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)... Which works in three steps:

## 1. Define `build` method in bundle

I choosed `AppBundle` because it is **my** first bundle to load in `app/AppKernel.php`.

***src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php***

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new AppCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

## 2. Write your custom `CompilerPass`

Symfony serializers are all under the `serializer` service. So I just fetched it and added to it a `configurator` option, in order to catch its instanciation.

***src/AppBundle/AppCompilerPass.php***

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;



class AppCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->getDefinition('serializer')
            ->setConfigurator([
                new Reference(AppConfigurer::class), 'configureNormalizer'
            ]);
    }
}
```

## 3. Write your configurer...

Here, you create a class following what you wrote in the custom CompilerPass (I choosed `AppConfigurer`)... A class with an instance method named after what you choosed in the custom compiler pass (I choosed `configureNormalizer`).

> This method will be called when the symfony internal serializer will be created.

The symfony serializer contains normalizers and decoders and such things *as private/protected properties*. That is why I used PHP's `\Closure::bind` method to scope the symfony serializer as `$this` into my lambda-like function (PHP Closure).

Then a loop through the nomalizers (`$this->normalizers`) help customize their behaviours. Actually, not all of those nomalizers need circular reference handlers (like `DateTimeNormalizer`): the reason of the condition there.

***src/AppBundle/AppConfigurer.php***

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;



class AppConfigurer
{
    public function configureNormalizer($normalizer)
    {
        \Closure::bind(function () use (&$normalizer)
        {
            foreach ($this->normalizers as $normalizer)
                if (method_exists($normalizer, 'setCircularReferenceHandler'))
                    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object)
                    {
                        return $object->getId();
                    });
        }, $normalizer, $normalizer)();
    }
}
```

## Conclusion

As said earlier, I did it for my project since I dind't wanted FOSRestBundle nor any third party bundle as I've seen over Internet as a solution: not for that part (may be for security). My controllers now stand as...

```
<?php

namespace StoreBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;



class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/products")
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = $em->getRepository('StoreBundle:Product')->findAll();
        return $this->json(['data' => $data]);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/product")
     * @Method("POST")
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        throw new \Exception('Method not yet implemented');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/product/{id}")
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = $em->getRepository('StoreBundle:Product')->findById($id);
        return $this->json(['data' => $data]);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/product/{id}/update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     *
     */
    public function updateAction($id)
    {
        throw new \Exception('Method not yet implemented');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/product/{id}/delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        throw new \Exception('Method not yet implemented');
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! This is the very reason why compiler passed where created.

Comment: Too much possibilities, too little time, too little concise and good and too much too broad docs. And as a result of all that - as OP mentioned - he spent a week until he got to this perfect solution. That's a luxury many of us don't have. :(  Therefore, I'd personally go for this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286659/261332.

Comment: @urserfuser I read that solution, along with your comment. (1) Not every one have the luxury of time, that's why I posted the solution I found (2) As of the "perfect solution", I'll say it not so but I did not wanted to instantiate a serializer (JSON, XML, YAML, etc...) for each route of my API. (3) As of OOP design, I'm not proud of that \Closure::bind. Through it is core to php, I see much like it as a PHP design leak. (4) And finally, I'll still choose this solution over your's choice because Symfony will automatically handle JSON, YAML or XML format alike.